# finding missing dates in a time interval (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, missing-data

I am a bit of a noob with SQL, so I was searching for some bit of code that might help me find missing date values for a time interval when I stumbled upon this code.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate ='2014-03-01' SET @EndDate = GETDATE()

;WITH Dates(Date) AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @StartDate)) AS Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Date) AS Date
    FROM Dates
    WHERE Date <= @EndDate
)
SELECT d.Date, r.Value
FROM Dates d
LEFT JOIN Times r ON d.Date = r.Date
```

[Link to the code](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/874281/get-empty-or-null-data-rows-with-available-data-be)

It works really well for my problem but I am not able to understand how it increments the date.

I would ask the author but their blog no longer exists and their twitter is inactive too.

**Edit:** someone said the post is lacking a question. I want to know **how this CTE is recursively adding the +1 to each date from @StartDate to @EndDate.**

Comment: Your question is lacking a question.  Please clarify.

Comment: It's a recursive CTe; it recurses until it doesn't return any rows, and each iteration performs `DATEADD(day, 1, Date)`:.Effectively like `n = 1 , n = n + 1 = 2, n = n+ 1 = 3, n = n + 1 = 4....` . Though, if you're dealing with large date ranges, a Tally would be far more performant.

Comment: I  agree with @Larnu, that a materialized table (tally or calendar) is a better way to generate sequences of dates or integers. If you can't create one, it would be better to use a cross join rather than recursive CTE. See [this](https://www.dbdelta.com/calendar-table-and-datetime-functions/) for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recursive CTE, or [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql).

The first line of of the CTE `SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @StartDate)) AS Date` is the seed, or root portion. The next `UNION` section takes that date, adds a day, and recurses.

Notice that inside the `Dates` block you are selecting `FROM Dates`, so it will continue produce rows with an incremented date until the `WHERE` clause is satisfied.

Comment: Thanks, izzy. This explains what I was getting confused with. I didn't understand why it was recursive. Your comment about ```FROM Dates``` made it clear.